# Elixir: How to find ALL occurrences of a value from a list of tuples?

Tags: list, functional-programming, tuples, elixir, find-occurrences

Find all occurrences of `{1, _}`; in other words, all first element values that are 1 from each tuple in the list.

Consider the following input:

```
[
  {1, 0},
  {2, 2},
  {1, 1},
  {11, 1},
  {1, 3},
  {1, 2},
  {13, 1}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{1,0}, {1,1}, {1,3}, {1,2}]
```

I tried `Enum.find(tl(input), fn x -> elem(x, 0) == elem(hd(input), 0) end)`, but I realized that `Enum.find/2` only returns the first and only one element that matches the criteria or function, which is: `{1,1}`.

My goal is to find all tuples that contain `{1, _}`, where the first element must be 1 and the second element can be any value.

Comment: Show some [mre], that is some Elixir code, in your question. StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework webiste

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch “I tried …” part is exactly showing the attempt. Your claim is unfounded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you can use a comprehension with pattern-matching:

```
result = for x = {1, _} <- list, do: x
```

Any `x` that doesn't match the pattern `{1, _}` will be filtered out.

See the [documentation for `for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) for more information.

You could also use `Enum.filter/2` together with the `match?/2` macro to achieve the same result:

```
result = Enum.filter(list, fn x -> match?({1, _}, x) end)
```

`Enum.find/2` is useful when you are looking for a single element, e.g. if you want to find the first entry matching your condition.

Comment: `Enum.filter(list, &match?({1, _}, &1))` or `Enum.filter(list, fn {1, _} -> true; _ -> false end)` :) Actually, comprehensions rule, of course.